# Is there any cloud service that offers RHadoop framework rather than just Hadoop?

Tags: r, hadoop, cloud

Since, I am developing a POC application as of now so, I would prefer a free service as it makes no sense to spend money on an idea if concept doesn't work out finally.

PS: I did a google check but, mostly services are currently just offering Hadoop rather than RHadoop

Answer (score 0):

This article provides links to a slide deck about setting up RHadoop on Amazon EC2:

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/03/r-and-hadoop-step-by-step-tutorials.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll just give it a shot before marking correct in order to check whether it works as per I expected. Otherwise, I'll update.